# HTML ,create form post using given curl request

Tags: php, html, curl

i have created an html form like so

```
<h1><a>Create Event</a></h1>
        <form id="form_4068" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="https://siteName/applications/**{application_id}**/deployments.json">
                    <div class="form_description">
            <h2>Create Event</h2>
        </div>                      
            <ul >

            <li id="li_2" >
        <label class="description" for="element_2">Title </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_2" name="element_2" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_5" >
        <label class="description" for="element_5">User </label>
        <div>
        <select class="element select medium" id="element_5" name="element_5"> 
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                    <option value="1" >user1</option>
                    <option value="2" >user2</option>
                    <option value="3" >user3</option>
        </select>
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_1" >
        <label class="description" for="element_1">Application </label>
        <div>
        <select class="element select medium" id="element_1" name="element_1"> 
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="1" >App1</option>
<option value="2" >App2</option>
<option value="3" >App3</option>

        </select>
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_3" >
        <label class="description" for="element_3">Change Log </label>
        <div>
            <textarea id="element_3" name="element_3" class="element textarea small"></textarea> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_4" >
        <label class="description" for="element_4">Description </label>
        <div>
            <textarea id="element_4" name="element_4" class="element textarea small"></textarea> 
        </div> 
        </li>

                    <li class="buttons">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="4068" />

                <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
```

i was given the following CURL REQUEST

```
curl -X POST 'https://siteName.com/v2/applications/{application_id}/deployments.json' \
     -H 'X-Api-Key:123456789' -i \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d \
'{
  "deployment": {
    "Title": "string",
    "changelog": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "user": "string"
  }
}'
```

here is the php containing the curl commands

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://theSite.com/v2/applications/{application_id}/deployments.json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "\n'{");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "X-Api-Key: 123456789";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

i would like to give the html page so anyone could create the event using my API in the curl Request.

My question is :
after creating the form html page, how do i post into this url whith all the given content in the form and matching the requested curl ?

thanks

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff. Have you checked the PHP manual? http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: yes i did , i have created a php from the given curl , but when clicking the "post" button , the browser keeps showing me my code instead of creating the event in the other site ,

Comment: What do you mean by "showing me my code"? Do you see your PHP-code in the browser?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson , yes excatly.

Comment: Do you have a webserver with PHP-support, like Apache + mod_php or NIGNX with php-fpm installed? If you do, then it doesn't seem to be setup correctly.If you don't, you need to (or use [PHP's built in webserver](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), if you're running PHP 5.4 or above (which you definitely should do)).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson im working with a 3rd part ,and they gave me the curl request as it should be .. and i just decided to create a php form page, intead of using their " wizard" everytime

Comment: We have no idea who "they" are, what their "wizard" is or how you actually are trying to run your code, so it's impossible for us to help you with that issue. You need to contact "them" and ask. Any PHP-page needs to be executed on a server supporting PHP.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson
 for the simplicity im working with newRelic , i can create an event to track simply by filling parameters in their page,
i took all these parameters and created a web form , they provide a curl request code as they should accept it .
i didnt try to contact them as i assume it is a coding issue.
thanks for the quick reply

Comment: You still need a webserver with PHP-support to run your code, which seems to be your main issue.